Can't restore Maui packages targeting net8.0-ios and net8.0-android on Azure Devops Pipeline
i have a net8 maui app with the following target frameworks:
        <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;</TargetFrameworks>

i'm able to build, deploy and run on my physical device locally, however when i try to build the app inside an azure devops pipeline, the restore fails telling me

[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1202: Package Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility 8.0.72 is not compatible with net80-android (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0,Profile=android). Package Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility 8.0.72 supports:


net80 (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0)
net80-android34.0 (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0,Profile=android34.0)
net80-ios17.2 (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0,Profile=ios17.2)
net80-maccatalyst17.2 (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0,Profile=maccatalyst17.2)
net80-tizen8.0 (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0,Profile=tizen8.0)
net80-windows10.0.19041 (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0,Profile=windows10.0.19041)
net80-windows10.0.20348 (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0,Profile=windows10.0.20348)
netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)

this is not the only error i have. In particular i have some similar errors both on android and ios:

NU1202: Package Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility 8.0.72 is not compatible with net80-ios (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0,Profile=ios). Package Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility 8.0.72 supports:


net80 (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0)
net80-android34.0 (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0,Profile=android34.0)
net80-ios17.2 (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0,Profile=ios17.2)
net80-maccatalyst17.2 (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0,Profile=maccatalyst17.2)
net80-tizen8.0 (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0,Profile=tizen8.0)
net80-windows10.0.19041 (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0,Profile=windows10.0.19041)
net80-windows10.0.20348 (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0,Profile=windows10.0.20348)
netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)

i don't want to modify my code targeting a different set of TFWs, because for example the same pipeline on a github actions seems to work.
Even if the only way would be to change TFWs there are some mismatches on the ios version, like the example below:
NU1202: Package CommunityToolkit.Maui 9.0.3 is not compatible with net80-ios (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0,Profile=ios). Package CommunityToolkit.Maui 9.0.3 supports:

net80 (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0)
net80-android34.0 (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0,Profile=android34.0)
net80-ios17.5 (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0,Profile=ios17.5)
net80-maccatalyst17.5 (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0,Profile=maccatalyst17.5)
net80-tizen8.0 (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0,Profile=tizen8.0)
net80-windows10.0.19041 (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0,Profile=windows10.0.19041)

NU1202: Package Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility 8.0.72 is not compatible with net80-ios (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0,Profile=ios). Package Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility 8.0.72 supports:

net80 (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0)
net80-android34.0 (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0,Profile=android34.0)
net80-ios17.2 (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0,Profile=ios17.2)
net80-maccatalyst17.2 (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0,Profile=maccatalyst17.2)
net80-tizen8.0 (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0,Profile=tizen8.0)
net80-windows10.0.19041 (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0,Profile=windows10.0.19041)
net80-windows10.0.20348 (.NETFramework,Version=v8.0,Profile=windows10.0.20348)
netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)

here i see than CommunityToolkit.Maui 9.0.3 is compatible with net8.0-ios17.5 and Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility with net8.0-ios17.2.
i've tried to update the maui version to the latest stable 8.0.82 but the same issues appear.
here is my pipeline for ios:
trigger:
- develop

pool:
  vmImage: macos-14

variables:
- group: Maui

steps:

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: Install MAUI
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      dotnet nuget locals all --clear 
      dotnet workload install maui-android maui-ios

- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'bestshifts.p12'
    certPwd: $(p12Secret)
    keychain: 'temp'

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
    provProfileSecureFile: 'bestishifts-appstore.mobileprovision'


- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Add custom NuGet source'
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    arguments: 'sources add -name DevExpress -source https://nuget.devexpress.com/$(devExpressApiKey)/api'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Restore NuGet packages'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'https://nuget.devexpress.com/$(devExpressApiKey)/api'
    includeNuGetOrg: true

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Build iOS App'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      dotnet build -f net8.0-ios -c Release -p:ArchiveOnBuild=true -p:RuntimeIdentifier=ios-arm64 -p:CodesignKey="iPhone Distribution" -p:CodesignProvision="Automatic" -o ./artifacts


I can reproduce the same error with your yaml.
You cannot use https://nuget.devexpress.com/$(devExpressApiKey)/api as the vstsFeed in Restore NuGet packages, the parameter need to be the devops feed.

You can use dotnet restore with source to restore(link here):
dotnet restore your.sln --source "https://nuget.devexpress.com/$(devExpressApiKey)/api" --source "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
sample yaml:
- task: UseDotNet@2          # add dotnet task
  displayName: 'Use dotnet'
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '$(sdkversion)'

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: Install MAUI
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      dotnet nuget locals all --clear 
      dotnet workload install maui-android maui-ios

- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'bestshifts.p12'
    certPwd: $(p12Secret)
    keychain: 'temp'

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
    provProfileSecureFile: 'bestishifts-appstore.mobileprovision'

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'restore nuget source'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      dotnet restore MauiSample.sln --source "https://nuget.devexpress.com/$(devExpressApiKey)/api" --source "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Build iOS App'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      dotnet build -f net8.0-ios -c Release -p:ArchiveOnBuild=true -p:RuntimeIdentifier=ios-arm64 -p:CodesignKey="iPhone Distribution" -p:CodesignProvision="Automatic" -o ./artifacts



It works. Thanks

Glad to know it helps! Happy coding!
